# Fastest way to pass data between threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, disruptor-pattern

I'm not asking about the most idiomatic way using Background workers or thread pool or the TPL.

I'm trying to find out what approaches are the fastest when it comes to passing data from one thread to another using .NET

I'm currently playing around with a ring buffer with a write index and a read index.
This way, I don't have any thread synchronization at all except atomic operations on updating read/write index.
(I'm not 100% sure, but reading and ++ on integers are atomic in .NET, right? or can an integer be overwritten halfway when one thread reads it?)

```
                         Write Index
                              V
index 0 [_][_][_][_][_][_][_][_][_][_][_] --> higher index
               ^
           Read Index
```

Is this a reasonable approach when it comes to thread to thread communication?

I'm not using it for any real project, I just want to get a better grip on what works and what don't here.

**[edit]
Ok, I'm up for public shaming:**

https://gist.github.com/rogeralsing/8121376

How many holes are there in that code?

Comment: It is like regex, now you got two problems.  You can't reliably tell when the buffer is full, you can't block the producer, you can't block the consumer when the buffer is empty.  There is an idiomatic way but you don't want to hear about it.

Comment: @RogerAlsing Standard integer operations are NOT atomic.

Comment: @HansPassant I know that there are idiomatic ways for it, I have been using TPL for all sorts of things, I am just trying to see what is possible and what is not for specific use cases. and as stated, I'm not using this for any thing real, just learning.

Comment: ++ is **not** atomic. You can use `Interlocked.Increment` though...

Comment: If you have code that you belive works and you want it reviewed, you could consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on how you define "fastest" and "between threads".
I think `ConcurrentBag<T>` is a really nice way. If i remember correctly the implementation uses some kind of linked list to reduce the scope of most locks so it becomes more scalable.
Is it fast between 2 simple threads? you need to check, but it utilizes your cores so your application as a whole will run fast.

Comment: AFAIK, `ConcurrentBag` is optimized for the case when the same thread is both produces as well as consumer. For sending from one thread to another, I belive `ConcurrentQueue` will be faster.